# sum of minterm vs product of maxterm

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, digital-logic, karnaugh-map

Given the following Boolean expression of F(A,B,C): F(A,B,C) = A' + B + C'
Which of the following statements is/are true about the above expression?

(i) It is an SOP expression
(ii) It is a POS expression
(iii) It is a sum-of-minterms expression
(iv) It is a product-of-maxterms expression

The model answer for this question is i),ii) and iv)

My question is why is iii) not one of the answers? i drew the K-map and found out that its possible to derive such a sum-of-minters expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cluster of literals in a boolean expression forms a minterm or a maxterm only, if there are all literals (variables of the given function or their negation) included in it.

**A minterm is a product of all literals of a function, a maxterm is a sum of all literals of a function.**

In a K-map a minterm or a maxterm marks out only one cell. In a truth table a maxterm or a minterm matches only one row.

The following truth-table corresponds to the given function:

```
 index | a | b | c || f(a,b,c) | term matching the row/K-map cell
-------|---|---|---||----------|----------------------------------
   0   | 0 | 0 | 0 ||     1    | minterm: m0 = (¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c)
   1   | 0 | 0 | 1 ||     1    | minterm: m1 = (¬a⋅¬b⋅c)
   2   | 0 | 1 | 0 ||     1    | minterm: m2 = (¬a⋅b⋅¬c)
   3   | 0 | 1 | 1 ||     1    | minterm: m3 = (¬a⋅b⋅c)
-------|---|---|---||----------|----------------------------------
   4   | 1 | 0 | 0 ||     1    | minterm: m4 = (a⋅¬b⋅¬c)
   5   | 1 | 0 | 1 ||     0    | MAXTERM: M5 = (¬a + b + ¬c)
   6   | 1 | 1 | 0 ||     1    | minterm: m6 = (a⋅b⋅¬c)
   7   | 1 | 1 | 1 ||     1    | minterm: m7 = (a⋅b⋅c)
```

There is only one maxterm present in the truth table (and your K-map) and the only maxterm determining the function's output as logical 0. It is a valid product-of-maxterms expression, even if there is only one. It is also the same boolean expression as the original one, so that is a valid product-of-maxterms expression too.

**However, this is *not* a valid sum of minterms, because there is none:**

```
f(a,b,c) = ∏(5) = M5 = (¬a + b + ¬c)
```

**For the original expression to be also the sum of minterms, it would need to mark out every single *true/one* cell in your K-map separately like this:**

```
f(a,b,c) = ∑(0,1,2,3,4,6,7) = m0 + m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m6 + m7 =
         = (¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c)+(¬a⋅¬b⋅c)+(¬a⋅b⋅¬c)+(¬a⋅b⋅c)+(a⋅¬b⋅¬c)+(a⋅b⋅¬c)+(a⋅b⋅c)
```

**As you can see, even if these two boolean expressions are equivalent to each other, the original one (on the left side of the equation) is not written as the sum-of-minterms expression (on the right side of the equation).**

```
(¬a+b+¬c) = (¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c)+(¬a⋅¬b⋅c)+(¬a⋅b⋅¬c)+(¬a⋅b⋅c)+(a⋅¬b⋅¬c)+(a⋅b⋅¬c)+(a⋅b⋅c)
```

*Just any* product is *not* a minterm, so the original expression could be in the form of both the product of sum and the sum of products, but not the valid sum-of-minterms.

```
f(a,b,c) = (¬a + b + ¬c) = (¬a) + (b) + (¬c)
```

In the picture (created using latex) you can see the expression – it is the same in it's minimal DNF and minimal CNF – and the sum of minterms equivalent to it.

[image: K-maps with equivalent expressions.]

Comment: Hmmm, but  from your first diagram, you made 3 groups of four ones which basically correspond to A' + B + C'. As such doesn't this grouping make that expression a valid sum of minterms?

Comment: The first diagram indeed corresponds to the A'+B+C' expression. It is the original expression simplified to it's minimal DNF. It is *a sum*, but not a valid sum of **minterms**, because the A' is not a minterm, the B is not a minterm and the C' is also not a minterm. Not one of them is a product of **all literals** of the given function. A minterm would be for example (a⋅b⋅c), which marks out **only one cell** and matches **only one row** in the corresponding truth table. The (A'+B+C') expression is a valid maxterm marking out the zero and also a valid product-of-maxterms expression.

Comment: Oh! i think i got it. I must have mixed up sum of minterms with simplified sum of products. Thanks a lot for the help!